# Access ID of unknown child DIV with javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to access the id of an unknown div using its parent id. A simplified version of my html is something like:

```
<div id="firstId">
   <div id="secondId"></div>
</div>
```

Just to be clear, I don't know the id of the child div. Then, I am trying to use the DOM to access it with:

```
var idd = $(".firstId").children().attr("id");
alert(idd);
```

But I get an `undefined` alert ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vabm/otpmcf1o/1/)). Not sure what might be the problem.

Comment: You are trying to select by class .firstId. Change $(".firstId") to $("#firstId")

Comment: firstId is Id not a class use #firstId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided the Id and accessing it by using class selector, which is wrong. Try this:

```
var idd = $("#firstId").children().attr("id");
alert(idd);
```

Answer (score 1):

The id selector is #:

```
var idd = $("#firstId").children().attr("id");
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

Change `.firstId` to `#firstId`:

```js
console.log($("#firstId").children().attr("id"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstId">
   <div id="secondId"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

var idd = $("#firstId").children().attr("id");
alert(idd);
use **#** insetead of **.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#firstId').children().attr('id'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/otpmcf1o/3/